# Backbone.js only add to collection if success (200 status) from server

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, backbone.js

***Answer:***

I answered my own question and left it on here for anyone else that is wanting to know.
Pass {wait:true} in the second argument property.

```
this.collection.create({parameters},{wait:true});
```

***Original Post:***

```
this.collection.create({parameters});
this.collection.bind('add',   this.render, this);
```

When a model is created it sends a post request to the server and I either respond 200 or 404.  If the server responds with a 404 error then the model should not trigger an add event and render my view for that model.

Anyone have any ideas on how to avoid triggering the add event when the server claims no it wasn't with the error 404.  I was reading something about {wait:true}; however, I am not, exactly, sure how to use it.

http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-create

Comment: NM I figure it out.  pass {wait:true} in the arguments for create();

Comment: You can answer your own questions and accept your own answers BTW.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
this.collection.create({parameters}, {wait: true});
```